# Im running asset_path ('') within prawn and getting no getting my assets on deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, asset-pipeline, cdn, prawn

Im currently trying to use a custom font on a PDF Prawn document created on Ruby on Rails 4.0.13. I is important to note that I'm also using Cloudfront as a CDN for my assets.

To use my font, on production, I'm using:

```
font = asset_path ('font.ttf')
```

I did have to hack my path for my development environment and do this for development:

```
font = "#{Rails.root}/app/assets#{font_path('/fonts/font.ttf')}"
```

The interesting thing is that the error that I get is that:

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - //d3dlqweqee7.cloudfront.net/assets/FuturaLT-Light-a645a904861503731c3f3fb31c31109bd57c3e82447eac95ca81525374e6f05ac3e.ttf
```

And the asset is actually there EXCEPT i'm not getting the "https:" protocol.

As you can see:

MISING: "`https:`" then the rest of the string URL is perfect: "`//d3dlqweqee7.cloudfront.net/assets/FuturaLT-Light-a645a904861503731c3f3fb31c31109bd57c3e82447eac95ca81525374e6f05ac3e.ttf`"

If I could just add https to that string in my production environment, everything would be perfect.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: why does your font assignment have `/app/assets` but the resolved URL only have `/assets/`? What happened to that `app` dir?

Comment: That is just my config when running on development and everything goes smoothly. On production  I just use: "asset_path ('font.ttf')". Thats why my production resolved URl does not contain "app"

Answer (score 0):

Use [`asset_url`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_url). Basically it just calls [`asset_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_path) but adds `{ protocol: :request }` to the `options` parameter.

When `options[:protocol]` is set to `:request` it will use the URI scheme to construct the URL that was used in the request.